# mysqli_result could not be converted to int in

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to store the results of an SQL COUNT in a variable, then divise them, however i'm presented with the error:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in ----

```
$countrows = 'SELECT count(*) AS NumRows FROM time_slots';
$countresult = $db->query($countrows);

$something = $countresult/3 ;
echo $something;
```

I used `echo` to display the result while testing...
How do i fix this?

Comment: Does your echo display anything?

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory, `$db->query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object : http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need get first the result and store in a variable after do the math.

```
countrows = 'SELECT count(*) AS NumRows FROM time_slots';
$countresult = $db->query($countrows);
$count = $countresult->fetch_assoc();               
$something = $count['NumRows']/3 ;
echo $something;
```